# How correctly display item with comments using 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have made something like facebook wall. I used 2 tables for storing info: #_*post and #*_post_comments. #_*post contains wall post and #*_post_comments contains post's comments.

I want to know how can I display all the info, using 2 separate models(for each query) or using join. Right now I used really bad, in my opinion solution:

I created model for #__post table, and used query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM #__post
```

And then in template I made this:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
echo $post->title;
echo $post->text;
echo 'Comments start here';
$comments = "SELECT * #__post_comments WHERE id = $post->id";
foreach ($comments as $comments) {
echo $comments->comment;
etc...
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do differently is run one SQL query and then fill in the arrays in the loop.
Example (not tested):

```
$comments = "select * from post_comments 
  join posts on post_comments.post_id = posts.id 
  order by post_comments.id desc, posts.id desc";
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
  if (!$posts[$comment['post_id']]) {
    $posts[$comment['post_id'] = array("post_data" => XXX, "comments" => array(YYY));
  }
}
```

Then you would have to do some tricks with sorting maybe, but hope you get the idea.
So in the end you should have one $post array like this:

```
$posts = array(
  [0] => array(
    "post_data" => array("title" => "XXX", "create_time" => "YYY"),
    "comments" => array(...)
  ),
  [1] => array(
    "post_data" => array("title" => "XXX", "create_time" => "YYY"),
    "comments" => array(...)
  ),
  /* ... */
);
```

It might be not pretty in terms of PHP, but you could save tons of executing time with one SQL query instead of N queries.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand u correctly... My query results are already stored in object, if I gonna use join query, then echoing results would be something like this. `echo $results->post; echo $results->post_comment;` But my problem here is if I use foreach for echoing results, i'll have a #__post items near each comment.

Comment: Well, my code wasn't really 100% ready, you have to tweak it for yourself, I was just trying to explain the basic idea.
Yes, the tricky thing here is to echo with foreach.
It should be like 
`foreach ($posts as $post) {
  echo $post['title']; // and other main post data
  foreach ($post['comments'] as $comment) {
    echo $comment['comment_text']; // one comment data
  }
}`

Comment: Sorry, still trying to figure out how to properly highlight the code in comments.

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4765
            [up] => 67
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4765
            [up] => 88
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4765
            [up] => 50
        )

)`

Comment: I dont really understand how I can do that with object.. If u feel u want help me.. above I posted output of object, `id`(column) is from #__post and `up` is from #__post_comments.